# Do you earn XP for partial matches in Titanfall?

Tags: titanfall

When playing Titanfall matches (campaign, if that makes any difference), if you quit before the end of a match do you still keep any earned XP? Or is it lost?

I was able to play last night, but only for about 6 minutes; but during those 6 minutes I did really, really well! However I had to quit immediately when the baby woke up...

Comment: I'm not sure but a way to check it yourself is look at your XP before a game, play it half-way, and then quit and see if your XP was changed.

Also, when something like that comes up, just hold of respawning and wait for the game to end so you can at least hopefully finish that match before getting kicked for inactivity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You keep all rewards and progression you got up until you leave. You don't get the bonus exp for finishing the match, or the regeneration multiplier, but all burn cards you collect, completed challenges, exp you've earned during play, and unlocks will stay.

Comment: The regen multiplier seems to apply. I checked by playing a match, leveling up, then quitting. The level up is recorded along with the item that was unlocked, and the multiplier is listed in the XP gained to level up. Might have been a change since this answer was posted though.

Answer (score 0):

No.

If you don't get to the end of the match, you don't get any XP, Challenge Progression or Burn Cards (either used or earned) will also be unaffected. This can happen if the connection to the server cuts out while it is loading the match results screen, as well as deliberately quitting a match early.

Comment: This is false, I've gotten cards and completed challenges then quit out of the match to go to a different mode (last titan standing to quickly finish off titan weapon challenge)